Why is there always 1 open bounty?
Is this to encourage answers, since we have a kinda low answer rate, or is there some other incentive there I'm missing?

I think this is just a coincidence. :-)

Just started two bounties; problem solved :-)

In general, I would say that it is a coincidence. There's been quite a lot of time over the last few months where there have not been any bounties, and at the time of posting there are two bounties. 
We're not a huge site at the moment, so the number of bounties is probably going to range between 0 and 3 for quite a while.
I've been experimenting a little bit with bounties over the last couple of months to give a little extra attention to some unanswered questions. I generally only do one at a time. And in general, a bounty poster  might be inclined to think that if there are no current bounties, this might be a good time to post a bounty. So that might contribute to the apparent persistence of one bounty. 

My question had a bounty yesterday, and at that time there were two bounties (including mine).  Going with the people above, they are coincidences. My question actually had a lot of answers but a highly specific criteria. 
